# Laurent's series for the function $\frac{1}{z^2+z}$ on the annular region $1<|z|<R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I am studying alone complex variables cause I'm not having class this year due to this pandemic. Now I started to study Laurent's series and I would love to know the answer of this question just to take a start point to move on with my exercises. If somebody could help me I'll be extremely grateful.

Comment: Write it as ${1 \over z^2} {1 \over 1+{1 \over z}}$ and expand the latter term for $|z|>1$ as $1 - {1 \over z} + {1 \over z^2} + \cdots$.

Comment: Is $R$ fixed in this problem?

Comment: Yes. R is a fixed number

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for any $R\gt1$, by writing $1/(z^2+z)=1/z\cdot1/(z+1)=1/z-1/(z+1)=1/z-1/z\cdot1/(1-(-1/z))=1/z-1/z\cdot\sum_{n\ge0}(-1/z)^n$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I did it! I spent so much time to solve this and now I am relieved to move on.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate $ \oint_C \frac{dz}{z²+z}$ where $C$ is a circumference defined  by $|z| < R$ using laurent series?

Comment: I think you can use the residue theorem.  You can calculate the residues using Laurent series.  But there are other ways.

Comment: Oooooh, so that is it! Residues is the next content. I was talking with a friend and he said to use residues to solve this. Maybe next week I can study this chapter. I was searching for laurent series exercises and examples. I thought this exercise could be solved only using series, but I was wrong.